# Design to avoid binding lvalue reference to temporary for data container and wrapper

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with the design of a few (probably two) C++ classes that work together and implement sort of a data container (Vector) and a data wrapper (Integer) that wraps individual vector elements (or better to say the access to it).
The Vector simply holds a vector of `int`.
The Integer/wrapper provides access to an `int` (possibly without holding it).

Requirements:

1. Wrapper/Integer must be available as lvalue
2. The data container should hold the data as an vector of `int` (not as a vector of Integer)
3. The wrapper also holds some other data members (no reinterpreting cast `int` -> Integer possible)

I fail to design this (see below) without running into the problem where an lvalue reference cannot bind to a temporary. I understand that that's not possible and I understand that code is wrong (and why it's wrong). There's no need to explain that lvalue references can't bind to rvalues. I'm struggling to find a solution to above requirements without this problem.

How to design this in C++? (Can be any modern standard)

```
#include<vector>
        
class Integer
{
  int& ref_t;
  bool other_data_member;

public:
  Integer(int& rhs): ref_t(rhs) {}

  Integer& operator=( int i )
  {
    ref_t = i;
    return *this;
  }
};



class Vector
{
  std::vector<int> data;

public:
  Vector(): data(10) {}
  
  Integer& operator[](int i)
  {
    return Integer( data[i] ); // caution: this doesn't work
  }
};



void write_one( Integer& i )
{
  i = 1;
}


int main()
{
  Vector v;
  write_one( v[5] );
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want `Integer` to hold a reference to an `int`. With the POD types, you're not making any efficiency gains and only inviting trouble.

Comment: @sweenish I think `Integer` must hold that reference since the data is not owned by that class. It's owned by the `Vector` class - `Integer` solely provides the access to it.

Comment: You are trying to return a reference to a function-local temporary. This is never a good idea. Since your `Integer` already holds a reference, just return it by value.

Comment: Can you change it to: `Integer operator[](int i)` ?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Intriguing idea. Then there's an extra copy involved and I'd need to see what happens with the other data members of Integer.. But surely an idea to test out!

Comment: @SergeyA see above

Comment: @ritter, I don't want to say something stupid, but is the scenario you describe vaguely similar to that of the infamous `std::vector<bool>`, where `operator[]` gives you a proxy?

Comment: @Enlico Yes, I think this is related. In case of the `bool` proxy the `operator[]` also returns by value. I think this might be the only way.

Comment: @ritter yeah, but that's not the end of the world.. i mean, references are just constant pointers which are automatically deferenced, just to say, and that pointer gets passed by value anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a “temporary” by value doesn’t make a **copy** or even a move (guaranteed as of C++17, though often implemented as a conforming optimization in prior versions).  You *have* to do this, because your `operator[]` needs to form a *new* wrapper for whatever index.  (The `reinterpret_cast` approach has undefined behavior regardless of other members of `Integer`.)  Generic code can bind `auto&&` to your proxy object because of **lifetime extension**, and can assign to it, so often need not be aware of the proxy (as is desirable).

Separately, if you want to avoid copying arguments to functions like `write_one` that do know about the proxy type, you can accept `const Integer&`.  To make that work, make your `operator=` **const** (which sounds weird until you remember that it’s not the `Integer` that’s being modified).